# Verifying general solution to differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica

to the following differential equation:

$y^{(6)}-2y'''+y=0$

I obtained the following general solution:

$y=C_1e^x+C_2x e^x+C_3e^{-x/2}\cos(x\sqrt3)+C_4xe^{-x/2}\cos(x\sqrt3)+C_5e^{-x/2}\sin(x\sqrt3)+C_6xe^{-x/2}\sin(x \sqrt3)$

I would like to verify that this is correct, since when I plug the function $y$ back into the original diff eq using Mathematica I do not get zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic equation is 
$$m^6-2m^3+1=0$$
$$(m^3-1)^2=0$$
$$(m^3-1)(m^3-1)=0$$
$$(m-1)(m^2+m+1)(m-1)(m^2+m+1)=0$$
the roots are
$$x_0=1$$
$$x_1=1$$
$$x_2=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$
$$x_3=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$
$$x_4=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$
$$x_5=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$

we see there are repeated roots

so the solution should be
$$y=C_1e^x+C_2x e^x+C_3e^{-x/2}\cos(x\sqrt3/2)+C_4xe^{-x/2}\cos(x\sqrt3/2)+C_5e^{-x/2}\sin(x\sqrt3/2)+C_6xe^{-x/2}\sin(x \sqrt3/2)$$

Comment: thanks somehow I forgot to divide the $\sqrt3$ by 2

Comment: @user32882 you are welcome